# Convert a text file to UTF8 in D

Tags: text, utf-8, character-encoding, d

I'm attempting to use the Phobos standard library functions to read in any valid UTF file (UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32) and get it back as a UTF-8 string (aka D's `string`). After looking through the docs, the most concise function I could think of to do so is

```
using std.file, std.utf;

string readToUTF8(in string filename)
{
    try {
        return readText(filename);
    }
    catch (UTFException e) {
        try {
            return toUTF8(readText!wstring(filename));
        }
        catch (UTFException e) {
            return toUTF8(readText!dstring(filename));
        }
    }
}
```

However, catching a cascading series of exceptions seems extremely hackish. Is there a "cleaner" way to go about it without relying on catching a series of exceptions?

Additionally, the above function seems to return a one-byte BOM in the resulting string if the source file was UTF-16 or UTF-32, which I would like to omit given that it's UTF-8. Is there a way to omit that besides explicitly stripping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your questions answers the other: the BOM allows you to identify the exact UTF encoding used in the file.

Ideally, `readText` would do this for you. Currently, it doesn't, so you'd have to implement it yourself.

I'd recommend using `std.file.read`, casting the returned `void[]` to a `ubyte[]`, then looking at the first few bytes to see if they start with a BOM, then cast the result to the appropriate string type and convert it to a `string` (using `toUTF8` or `to!string`).

Comment: And what would you suggest for a UTF-16 or UTF-32 string lacking a BOM?

Comment: How would you identify the encoding without one? UTF-8 is nice in that a random byte string is unlikely to ever validate, but utf-16 and utf-32 would need to be... I think guessing based on the number of zeroes you encounter without the BOM or something like a file extension to let you know.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm sorry if these are silly questions; I've very recently awoken from the "all text is ASCII" dream and am trying to handle Unicode the best I can.

Comment: Here's an example of encoding detection gone wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts